Invalid CreatedTime value is received when listing files using Google Drive API
When using the Google Drive API to list files in a certain drive, some of the files are returned with a CreatedTime value of "2038-01-19T03:14:07.999Z" (which is the Y2038 bug timestamp).
Here's what I tried to do:
apiCall := svc.Files.List().
    Fields("files(id,createdTime,description)").
    Q("trashed=false").
    IncludeItemsFromAllDrives(true).
    SupportsAllDrives(true)

files, err := call.Do()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

for _, file := range files.Files {
    fmt.Println(file.CreatedTime)
}

When printing the CreatedTime value, I expected all of the timestamps to be of a date before today. However, several timestamps are actually of "2038-01-19T03:14:07.999Z"
So, my question is - what does this CreatedTime mean for a file? Is it even a valid file?
Or, rather, am I missing something here?
Thank you!

Have you tried printing which files have that timestamp? Have you checked in Google Drive what their actual timestamp is?

Everything else about the file seems to be valid - the file name, type, modified time, etc. However, since this is a problem I encountered while in work, I don't have access to the file itself since it's a customer's file.
